# pytest is not running conftest.py to pick up custom command args

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.9

In a project im working on we have a step where we export a csv before exporting we run a regression test step against the report using pytest. pytest is invoked using the following command

```
    def _invoke_pytest(self):
    pytest.main(['src/tests/regression/regression_tests.py'
                ,"-m",self.expectations_suite
                ,'--sample', self.sample_filepath
                ,'--expectations',self.expectations_suite_filepath
                ,'--report-log',self.logs_report_filepath])
```

--sample and --expectations are custom args defined in the conftest.py using the following

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--sample", default=False)
    parser.addoption("--expectations", default=False)
```

when calling this code locally it works pytest finds the conf but when inside a docker container it doesnt pick up the conftest and therefore fails on running pytest.
a simplified folder layout is as follows

```
src/
├─ main/
│  ├─ export
│  ├─ invoke_pytest
├─ test/
│  ├─ regression/
│  │  ├─ conftest
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is there any difference in the working directory when you run it locally compared to when you run it in Docker?

Comment: @tmt the whole src file is copied over to /app/src and then ran within there so the file structure will be identical

Comment: Sure but you have `pytest_addoption(parser)` in _src/test/regression/conftest.py_, right? Those options would therefor work only when you run your tests within _src/test/regression/_ and they wouldn't be collected otherwise. So what is your [current/working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) when you run it locally and when you run it in Docker?

Comment: @tmt ah sorry, when running in docker it runs from within main ( there is a line that  and then locally with the vs code debug with the path set to  ./src/main/export.py which picks up the extra args and runs the tests

Comment: this was the issue moving conftest into the src folder allowed pytest to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was fixed by moving conftest into the src folder allowed pytest to find it